# In Java taking parameters as char but without quotes

Tags: java

I have defined a method with a parameter of type `char`:

```
public void method(char x){
    // do something here
}
```

I would like to be able to call this method like this:

```
method(a);
```

But Java wants me to instead write:

```
method('a');
```

How can I call the method without quotes? Does Java support that?

Comment: The short answer is: No, Java does not support that. But this sounds like an X-Y problem: there is probably a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: The other short answer is "yes" -- if `a` is a char variable

Comment: I mean, short of defining a variable with the name `a`. You could of course do `public static final char a = 'a';` and so forth for all the letters in the alphabet, but that would just be silly.

Comment: Is there any language out there which supports this syntax?

Comment: @LongNguyen: Perl and Bash both do, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for this to be legal syntax:

```
method(a);
```

Is for something in scope to define `a`.  For example, you could do:

```
class Foo {
    public static final char a = 'a';
    // etc.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(a);  // equivalent to method('a')
    }
}
```

But unless you create a variable with the name `a`, you will not be able to use `a` as a bare word in Java program source. If you want a *char literal*, you need to use single quotes, like `'a'`.